# How to catch the key values from a custom keyboard on Android mobiles or tablets? How to make work an Android Keyboard & Barcode Scanner within Odoo?

Tags: android, jquery, keyboard, odoo, keyboard-events

I am trying to use **Odoo** with the application [**Barcode & QR code Keyboard**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nikosoft.nikokeyboard), from Nikola Antonov (just an example, I do not know if there are better options), in order to read barcodes for the pickings.

The first problem I had to face was I had to show the keyboard in this picking view

[image]

So I needed to create an input field in order to click in it and show the Android Keyboard, or in this case the Nikola Antonov keyboard. Then, I had to assign the function handler to this input text field:

```js
this.$('#input_text_barcodes').on('keyup', self.getParent().barcode_scanner.handler);
```

The function is only working as expected if I use the normal Android Keyboard (AOSP) and only with numbers. The letters of the Android Keyboard or whatever character of the Nikola Antonov Keyboard are not working (only the backspace)

```js
this.handler = function(e){
    self.$('#aux_label').text('>> CODE: ' + e.which)
    self.$('#aux_label').text('>> KEY CODE: ' + e.keyCode)
    self.$('#aux_label').text('>> KEY: ' + e.key)

    // [...]
```

I tried switching the languages of the keyboard as well, but with the same result

- Should I change the `keyup` event?
- Is there other way to catch the characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have asked to the developer of the application directly and he solved the problem quite fast. He made it work with numeric keys, that is enough for what I wanted to achieve.